# PHP and Javascript make comparisons differently?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The below `PHP` code outputs **Yes**

```
if("2"== true){
    echo "yes";
}
else{
echo "no";
}
?>
```

But the below `Javascript` code alerts **No**

```
 <script>
    if("2" == true){
            alert('yes');
        }
        else{
            alert('no');

        }
   </script>
```

I dont knw how these statements will execute in other languages. Why the outputs are different?

Comment: always use === instead of ==. When using == javascript and php will try to typecast, and sometimes guess the type wrong.

Comment: Because different languages are different and make different decisions about what equality means.

Comment: `if ("2") {
   //this will be executed!!!!
}`

Comment: @downvoters: Whats wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP "==" just checks if the value is set, then it is automaticly true.

In JS there will be a type conversion to check the values.  True will be converted to "1" and  "1" is not equal to "2".

Answer (score -1):

In PHP you need to check with `===` to check also the datatypes

```
if ("2" === true) {

}
```

See what happens when PHP casts your string to bool:

```
php > var_dump ((bool) "1234");
bool(true)
php > var_dump ((bool) "");
bool(false)
```

See [PHP Reference](https://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.comparison.php)